# How to customize Telerik Blazor-UI grid filter options for entire grid when using filter-row?

Tags: razor, telerik, blazor, blazor-server-side, telerik-grid

I have a grid such as the below. **How can I restrict the filter options for all grid columns to only 'Equals' and 'Contains' when `FilterMode` is set to `FilterRow`?**

```
@using Telerik.DataSource;

<TelerikGrid Data=@Products
            Pageable="true"
            Groupable="true"
            Sortable="true"
            FilterMode="GridFilterMode.FilterRow">
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="ProductName" Title="Product Name" />
        <GridColumn Field="UnitPrice" Title="Cost">
    </GridColumns>
</TelerikGrid>
```

In the Kendo-UI version of the grid, we could specify the [filterable.options](https://www.telerik.com/forums/filter-menu-only-allow-contains-option) in the grid schema, or globally.

I've been reading the [Blazor-UI API docs](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/api/Telerik.DataSource.FilterDescriptor), but I'm not seeing anything useful.

The docs for [Filter-Row Config](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/grid/filter/filter-row#configuring-the-filter-row) don't seem to indicate a way to restict the filter options either.

Answer (score 1):

This will come in a future release, follow it at [this page](https://feedback.telerik.com/blazor/1550855-provide-a-way-to-customize-the-filteroperators-in-the-filter-dropdownlist)

For now, only using a filter template will let you do that by customizing everything in it